# Cut value in dataframe value on index obtained by REGEX

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have location in the column 'ville' as the format 'Paris 75000' or 'Paris 75000 foobar'

I would like to keep only chain before zipcode in column 'ville'

I try to decompose the task

```
ville = 'Paris 75000 foo'
index = re.search(r"[0-9]", val).start()-1
print(ville[0:index]
```

It seems the result is good
my REGEX give me the index of the first number
and the slice is ok

But I have difficulties to implement in my dataframe

I tried :

```
data['ville']= data['ville'].apply(lambda x: re.split(r" [0-9]", x))
```

But I obtained several values by row in a python list

I tried also with slice method on the column but I can not found the good syntax

an idea ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['ville'] = df['ville'].str.split(' [0-9]+').str[0]
```